# background occlusion

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render 2 scenes. The first scene is just a 2D background plane. In the second scene i have set to objects. The first objects (a head) material-opacity is set to 1. I thought this was an easy and fast way to calculate the occlusion for the second object (sunglasses) in the scene. In fact that work exactly like I wanted, but now the head is also occluding the background even though he should be transparent. ( I cleared the depth buffer before rendering the second scene and set `renderer.autoClear = false` )

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
var headMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, opacity: 1 });
...
//Renderloop
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( background, camera );
renderer.clear(false,true,false);
renderer.render( scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a compelling reason for rendering two scenes, rather than just one scene that contains all objects? They share the same camera, no?

Try rendering the head and sunglasses first. Mask the sunglasses with a stencil. Then render the background with a stencil test (but not depth test). You'll render fewer background pixels, resulting in a bit faster overall render.

Comment: Okay, but I dont really know how to do that and i cant find any examples to how to mask with stencil. Also I dont know how to specify the rendering order of the objects...I would appreciate any examples and links if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If by saying "background" you mean a scene with only plane that has some texture on in - why don't you set your background as html background? That was you won't have to calculate your plane's right position to fill all thre screen area.

Now, for transparency issue - here is some example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ajJmx/1/

See how you've got your front cube side set to semi-transparent and you can see othe sides of cube. And if you turn cube 45deg - you'll see that even though there is some other object on the background - your solid cube sides stay solid.

What you basically want to do is to set `transparent:true, opacity:0.6` to your sunglasses material. That's it! You could also play around with material blendings and try to set `blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending` depending on you sunglasses type.

Comment: Okay I got it working. Setting the background in the body instead of rendering it on a plane texture did the trick. Its not really how I wanted it to work, but it works. For the correct occlusion i set the heads material to transparent: false, opacity: 0 AND color: 0x000000. Not sure why but it only works by setting the color to black. Thanks Alex.

Comment: You are welcome! Keep on that study and together we'll build a better web!))